# A problem about checking isomorphism of R-module

Tags: modules, module-isomorphism

Let $R=K\left[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\right]$ be a polynomial ring with coefficients in the field $K$; $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_p,\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots,\beta_q\in R^{1\times m}$; $M_1$ be the $R$-module generated by $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_p$; and $M_2$ be the $R$-module generated by $\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots,\beta_q$. How to check if $R^{1\times m}/M_1\cong R^{1\times m}/M_2$ is true or not?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Point 1) Please enclose math in dollar signs (double dollar signs if applicable). That will make the MathJax engine kick in and format it to look nice. Point 2) Please don't enclose text in dollar signs. That way it's much more readable, and you can actually use spaces rather than \; everywhere.

Comment: @arthur,@lord-shark-the-unknown,thanks!

Comment: I’m not sure your question has a good answer in general. For example, one could take $R=k[x]$, $M_1= \langle x \rangle$, and $M_2= \langle x^2 \rangle$. Then $M_1$ is isomorphic to $M_2$ but the quotients are different